# Migrating from Linksys by Cisco Router as DNS and DCHP Server to A Dell PowerEdge Windows Server 2008 R2 Box?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, xen

Okay so, I am not the best at this stuff, but I am going to try this.  Okay, so, currently we have a Linksys by Cisco E2000 Router running our DCHP, as well as our DNS Server.  We just purchased a Dell PowerEdge T110 with Dual Gigabit Ethernet Ports, with XenServer Free Edition Installed, I am using a Windows 2008 R2 Standard License as one of the Xen VM's, which I want to run our DCHP and DNS Server on, as well as our Web Hosting.  Can someone please explain to me, how I need to set up my DCHP, DNS, and Web Hosting system, or point me in the direction I should be going in. As I said, I'm new to this and I am more of a computer tech, than a Server Administrator.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: If you have little experience in any of these systems your company may want to look into getting a consultant in to help with the setup.  The setup and design of each of these is very dependent on what you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it may not be a good idea to put your Web server role on the same machine as your DHCP, maybe setup a second VM for web and start put by enabling the application server role. Secondly, regarding your DHCP, plan out your scope, exclusions for static IPs in your environment and how you would like to setup your network core. A good starting place would be to familiarize yourself with the concepts before implementation, and have a plan in place; this link might help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778368%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Alright, can you explain to me why it wouldn't be a good idea to put them on the same machine?

Comment: Your web server is external facing i.e. facing the internet and you would want to separate your web server from internal servers like putting it in a DMZ.